# How do i calculate the average with certain condition in R?

Tags: r

I've been trying to calculate the average of a column with condition in a dataframe and plot it in a graph. But so far I can only get the average of the whole column with `mean(df$Age)`. [Sample dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fmTO.png)

What I'm trying to get is the average age of employees in Vancouver but I'm not sure how to do it so I can't plot it out.

Comment: `mean(df$Age[df$CityName == 'Vancouver'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get average of a specific city you can subset it and take `mean`.

```
result <- mean(df$Age[df$CityName == 'Vancouver'], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
tribble(
  ~Age, ~City,
  61, "Vancouver",
  58, "Vancouver",
  48, "Terrace",
  48, "Terrace"
) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  summarise(Age = mean(Age))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   City        Age
#>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 Terrace    48  
#> 2 Vancouver  59.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>